# CMake Project structure: When to use add_library/target_link_library over target_sources?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm creating a C++ project in which I can compartmentalize my source code in the following way

```
project
│   README.md
│   Dockerfile    
│   CMakeLists.txt <---- Entrypoint
│
└───lib/spdlog (headers)
│
└───src
│   │   main.cpp
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │
│   └───mongo
│   │   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │   mongo.h
│   │   │   mongo.cpp
│   │   │   mongo_utils.h
│   │   │   mongo_utils.cpp
│   │   │   ...
│   │
│   └───core
│       │   CMakeLists.txt
│       │   some_stuff.h
│       │   some_stuff.cpp
│       │   ...
│   
└───tests
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │   tests
```

I'm trying to create a solid structure with CMake. I noticed that I have the following options:

- Either compile all of the subdirectories in src as libraries using `add_library` and tie them up in the src/CMakeLists.txt where I create my executable using only the main.cpp source file. The downside to this approach is that all libraries depend on the spdlog header files, and core depends on the other libs in src like mongo.
- Simply use `target_sources` in each directory and use all these files in the `add_executable` in src/CMakeLists.txt

I have the feeling that I should make the modules into libraries whenever they do not depend on other code, such as mongo (standalone mongocxx wrapper). If however, mongo where to depend on files in core (having a circular import so to say), then I would use `target_sources` to wrap them all together in `add_executable`.

Is this correct? And is using `add_library` wherever possible the prefered way? How do we efficiently include the lib/spdlog header files in each library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling separated libraries for each part of a program is usually preferable. This is useful since you can have multiple executable linking to it. For example, automated tests usually are separated executable targets that need to call the part that is testing.

It can also be useful since different part of your program may link to different external libraries, sometimes privately.

However, `target_sources` is still useful. If you have a source code generator for one of your libraries, you may want to add the generated sources in a different place than the place you call `add_library` to keep the build clean.

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you! Consider the example where I have the library mongo, where mongo/mongo.h includes core/some_stuff.h, and core/some_other_stuff.h includes mongo/mongo.h. So mongo lib depends on core and vice versa. How can I handle this problem while still having a mongo/core library? Is this possible or should I pack them together with `target_sources`? Additionally, is having to compile all the libs with spdlog header files overhead that we can avoid?

Comment: @laurensvm This is a circular dependency. My suggestion would be to break the circular dependency by breaking a module in multiple modules. However, circular dependencies between libraries is permitted. Simply call `target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC lib2)` and vice versa. If you only include the files in cpp, you can set the link to `PRIVATE`.

Comment: For clarity, I'm assuming "compiling separated libraries ... is usually preferable" because those libraries can be compiled *once* and linked against several executables. That's more efficient than compiling the libraries once *per* executable for every executable associated with the library source files via `target_sources`.

Comment: @6equj5 exactly